# Fixing burned carpet

Tags: cleaning

I was recently trying to get candle wax off my carpet using iron which was affective but I forgot that I was running out of paper and that left a burn on my carpet which I m sad about as I am a on rent. How can I removed the black burn area without discolouring or damaging the carpet? 
[image: burned carpet]

Answer (score 4):

The best you can hope for without replacing that section of carpet (which is possible), get some [angled sewing scissors](http://m.havelssewing.com/fabric-scissors-multi-angled-fabric-scissors.html). [image: sciscors]You May be able to find them at a fabric store, or online for less. Link included for reference.

Carefully snip off the burned discolored segment of carpet fiber, keeping the scissor blades level with the floor as to make the cuts least noticeable. Because this is a low-pile carpet, you must be careful to cut as little off as possible.

Trim through a small section, then stand up and see if the cut section looks okay. If not, you must replace the entire section of carpet which is a much bigger job, but can be done.

Try this method. If it doesn’t work, come back and I will give instructions to replacing a section of carpet. Good luck.